# adding a next button in swiper in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

here is the sample code :

```
import "./introslider.css";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Hand from "../../images/hand_1.png";
import Sabad from "../../images/group_2.png";
import Cart from "../../images/credit_card_35.png";
// Import Swiper styles
export default class IntroSlider extends Component {
  state = {
    slides: [
      {
        Logo: Hand,
        Hit: "lorem[enter image description here][1]",
        Text: "lorem",
      },
      {
        Logo: Sabad,
        Hit: "lorem",
        Text: "lorem",
      },
      {
        Logo: Cart,
        Hit: "lorem",
        Text: "lorem",
      },
    ],
  };
  handleclick = () => {
    const swiper = new Swiper(".sliderStyle", {
      // ...
    });
    swiper.on("slideChange", function () {
      console.log("slide changed");
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Swiper
          cssMode={true}
          navigation={true}
          pagination={true}
          className="sliderStyle"
          dir="ltr"
          // // install Swiper modules
          // // modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
          spaceBetween={50}
          slidesPerView={1}
          // navigation
          // pagination
          // scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}

          // onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
        >
          {this.state.slides.map((slide, index) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={index}>
              <div className="row">
                <img style={{ width: "120px" }} src={slide.Logo} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className="row">{slide.Hit}</div>
              <div className="row">{slide.Text}</div>
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleclick}>
                next
              </button>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the page have 3 card of swiper and everything worked except the next button. and
when the blue next button is clicked it shpould move to the next slider. But I do not know how to handle it. thanks for your answer:)
and we are using swiperJs/react (https://swiperjs.com/react).

Comment: Did you perhaps find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add a div tag with className="next", preferably with some button or icon in it, like so -

```
 <div className="next">
    <Button> Next</Button>
    </div>
```